# Chrome Extension: How to send html form data to a php page upon button being clicked which redirects to said php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

so i have a chrome extension which has a form popup which contains butttons and editable fields which are autopopulated by my javascript functions and options page. It has the ability to send the form data to a php page 'PhpFile.php', upon clicking a button, which then inserts the data in a database using a query.

I also have another php page DataDisplayScript.php. This page is intended to display specific records in the database which match certain fields in the users form such as age and gender. At the minute i have a button on the chrome extension with some javascript called by it which takes me to this page but so far i can only get the page to load the whole data table when redirected to it. This is because it doesnt have any information about the user from the form.

My question is if its possible for when i click the button on my extension which redirects me to the DataDisplayScript can i send certain field values from the form to the php page? which i can then use to query the database for the matching records and display them on the page. (dont really need help with the query, just with sending the data upon the user clicking a button or a link).

Here is my html for the form involved in sending user information to DataDisplayScript.php

```
<form action="http://************/DataDisplayScript.php" method="POST" name="HiddenUIDPostForm">
        <input type = "text" id="UIDSuggestions" name="UIDSuggestions" hidden="true">
        <input type="text" id="Gender" name="Gender" placeholder="Your Gender"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Age" name="Age" placeholder="Your Age"><br/>
        <input type = "submit" name="uidSubmit" value="Go To Suggestions">
    </form>
```

Here is my javascript for the button which redirects me to the DataDisplay script page:

```
function ClickSuggestionsLink(data){
    /*if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","DataDisplayScript.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    */
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://***********/DataDisplayScript.php'});
}
```

Here is my php on DataDisplayScript which id like to store the form info sent

```
$uId = $_POST['UIDSuggestions'];
$gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$age = $_POST['Age'];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why did you comment out the AJAX part of the javascript. Viewing  the PHP script in a browser tab will not send it data and accept a reply, you have to use AJAX

Comment: I couldnt get it working mainly and thought id leave it in and come back to it if i couldnt find an alternative but if ajax is the only way do you see any problems with that commented out ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. AJAX with Post method.

```
function ClickSuggestionsLink(data){
    var dir = 'http://***********/DataDisplayScript.php';
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var uId = document.getElementById("UIDSuggestions").value;
    var gender = document.getElementById("Gender").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("Age").value;

    var data = "UIDSuggestions="+uId +"&Gender="+gender+"&Age="+age;

    request.open("POST", dir, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    request.onload = function() {
      if (request.status === 200) {
          // code if everything went fine
          // request.responseText for printing echoes
      } else {
          // code if otherwise
      }
    };

    // sending data here
    request.send(data);
}
```

Comment: At the minute this works in that the page is displayed in the popup of the extension, but i was hoping to have the button take me to the actual page in a new tab with the variables still present. however i get an undefined index error like before when i add the javascript for creating a new tab and redirecting to the page within the same function i placed your code. Any idea as to how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting what you are asking. Do you want to _redirect_ somehow after the ajax has done its work?

Comment: I would like to view the table in a new tab rather than in the chrome extension popup if its possible?

Comment: Well I'm not sure about this, but if you are displaying this table bellow the ```request.status === 200```, why not call the ```chrome.tabs.create``` there? Not sure how to help you with this, maybe you should create another question adding more info? I think I understood what you mean but I don't really know how does it work this so called new tab in chrome. Sorry about that!

Comment: No worries man ill maybe post it up as another question like you suggested if im having trouble. Thanks very much jserodio youve been a big help!